# How can I use Scheduler in multiple service?

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I've tried the following methods to use the scheduler, but I can't find an answer, so I'd like to ask you a question.
The scheduler service is running exactly on time.
However, only 'sessionService.getUserInfo()' runs.

We are not doing any work on youtubeSearchService.searchYoutube and youtubeSearchService.searchYoutube.

Why there's only work one service. I wonder what to do to use multiple services.

```
@Component
public class SchedulerService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerService.class);

    @Autowired
    private YoutubeSearchService youtubeSearchService;

    @Autowired
    private WeatherService weatherService;

    @Autowired
    private  SessionService sessionService;

    public static int i = 0;
    public static int j = 0;


    @Scheduled(cron="0 40 0/1 * * *") 
    public void weatherSchedulerService() throws Exception { 
        ++i;
        weatherService.insertRTweather(sessionService.getUserInfo());
    } 


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *") 

    public void youtubeSearchSchedulerService() throws Exception { 
        ++j;
        youtubeSearchService.searchYoutube(sessionService.getUserInfo(),j);
    }

}
```

Comment: Both schedules call getUserInfo so why is it significant that sessionService.getUserInfo() runs? Are you saying that only i increments?

Why don't you put a log in each method to check which of them are running?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what your problem is. You are scheduling `weatherSchedulerService` and `youtubeSearchSchedulerService` but then say "only 'sessionService.getUserInfo()' runs". That is not possible. Did you put a log as the first line of both methods to see that they are called ? Did you check the output of getUserInfo() (it might be null for example with a not null requirement in searchYoutube(). Did you check that youtubeSearchService is properly initialized ?

Answer (score -1):

I used to have challenges with spring scheduler, especially with annotation based config and finally use following solution I hope it helps:

SchedulerConfig.java using quartz

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig
{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SchedulerConfig.class.getName());

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean
public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory()
{
    AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    logger.info("Configuring Job factory");

    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
}

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(Trigger trigger, JobDetail job)
{

    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));

    logger.info("Setting the Scheduler up");
    schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
    schedulerFactory.setJobDetails(job);
    schedulerFactory.setTriggers(trigger);

    return schedulerFactory;
}

@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetail()
{

    JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(SchedulerService.class);
    jobDetailFactory.setName("Qrtz_Job_Detail");
    jobDetailFactory.setDescription("Invoke Sample Job service...");
    jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
    return jobDetailFactory;
}

@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger(JobDetail job)
{

    CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    //three am
    trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 3 * * ?");                
    trigger.setJobDetail(job);
    trigger.setName("Qrtz_Trigger");
    return trigger;
}

}
```

quartz.properties : put it in classptah

```
# thread-pool
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1

org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true

# job-store
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

# others
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
```

Your scheduler service define as follow :

```
@Component
public class SchedulerService implements Job {


@Autowired
private YoutubeSearchService youtubeSearchService;

@Autowired
private WeatherService weatherService;

@Autowired
private  SessionService sessionService;


public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
{
    weatherService.insertRTweather(sessionService.getUserInfo());
} 
}
```

if you want two define more than one schedule, you can it to schedulerconfig by **adding a jobdetail and trigger**.

Don't forget to add quartz jar file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: the question concerns scheduling and quartz is related to it and required for using scheduling in spring

Comment: You certainly do not need quartz to schedule in spring. You can, it does support quartz but it is not mandatory